# check if string follows specific list of strings in python regex

Tags: python, regex, list

I have a list of strings that I call 'text_sentences' of the type

```
["bla bla bla", "yada yada yada","foo boo, foo"...]
```

Then I have a list of specific strings (words) I have to use to identify the elements (sentences) in my `text_sentences`, which I call 'words'

```
words=["word1", "word2",..]
```

My aim is to identify the sentences in `text_sentences` based on `words`, i.e. if a sentence contain at least one of the words in `words`, that sentence (element of `text_sentences`) will be put into a new list, say it 'matched'. If not, put it in a list called 'unmatched'. I can reproduce this with something like

```
    matched=[]
    unmatched_sent=[]
    for j in range(len(text_sentences)):
        if any(s in text_sentences[j] for s in words):
            matched.append(text_sentences[j])
        else:
            unmatched.append(text_sentences[j])
```

However: this is only one step of the process I need to perform. In fact, I also have a list of words like negations of the type

```
negations=["no","not","none"]
```

Its use is the following: if a sentence in text_sentences contain at least one word in words, then that sentence must be appended to the `matched` list; if, however, the word from `words`that is contained in that sentence follow any word from the `negations`list, then that sentence must be appended to the list `unmatched`. If the sentence does not contain any word from `words`, then it must be appended to `unmatched`. How can I perform this all at once?

Comment: Make a variable for the previous word, if theres a match and the previous word is a negation, then unmatch instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
t = ["bla bla bla", "yada yada yada","foo boo, foo", "yoo no you are not in list"]
words = ["test", "bla", "yoo"]
negation = ["no","not","none"]
unmatched = []
matched = []
for i in words:
    for j in t:
        if i in j:
            matched.append(j)

for l in t:
    if l not in matched and l not in unmatched:
        unmatched.append(l)

for m in negation:
    for k in matched:
        if m in k:
            matched.remove(k)

print(unmatched)
print(matched)
```